# Audio stream recording and playback using Qt

Tags: qt, audio, multimedia

I am trying to develop a multimedia program using Qt which gets an audio input stream from a microphone (using `QAudioInput`), then stores the sampled bytes in memory for 60 milliseconds, then play it back (using `QAudioOutput`).

The [documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qaudiooutput.html#details) for `QAudioOuput` has an example which does most of this, but it uses a file as its data source instead. How can I modify this to use an input stream instead?

Answer (score 5):

[QAudioInput::start()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qaudioinput.html#start) and [QAudioOutput::start()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qaudiooutput.html#start) both take a pointer to a [QIODevice](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QIODevice.html) as a parameter.  This could be pointer to a [QFile](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html) (like in the example) or a [QBuffer](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qbuffer.html) if you want to keep the data in the memory.